# Getting all launchable apps on home like android home menu with bottom dots

Tags: java, android, android-launcher

Hi i am working on a custom launcher app.I want to get all launchable apps on home [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y7uN.png).
My Current Code:

> MainActivity.class

```
    import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycalview);
        LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(4, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL); // 2 is number of items per row
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager); // deafult
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        Intent main = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        main.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        List<ResolveInfo> launchables = pm.queryIntentActivities(main, 0);
        Collections.sort(launchables,
                new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, launchables, pm);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycalview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/battery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/hi"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> Adapter.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    List<ResolveInfo> lapps;
    Context context;
    PackageManager pm=null;
    public Adapter(Context context, List<ResolveInfo> apps, PackageManager pn) {
        this.context = context;
       lapps=apps;
       pm=pn;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Adapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.griditem, parent, false);
        Adapter.ViewHolder viewHolder = new Adapter.ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Adapter.ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        holder.images.setImageDrawable(lapps.get(position).loadIcon(pm));
        holder.text.setText(lapps.get(position).loadLabel(pm));
        holder.itemlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ResolveInfo launchable = lapps.get(position);
                ActivityInfo activity = launchable.activityInfo;
                ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                        activity.name);
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                i.setComponent(name);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lapps.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView images;
        TextView text;
        RelativeLayout itemlayout;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            images = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            itemlayout=view.findViewById(R.id.item);

        }
    }
}
```

> griditem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/item"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.RoundedImage"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/label"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I just want to show all apps on home screen with horizontal scroll with bottom dots.
I have also try [this method](http://shrikantsonarblogs.blogspot.com/2013/07/gridview-with-viewpager-like-android.html) but my issue can't solved

Comment: Can you be more clear about what your problem is?  What aren't you able to do, or what isn't working?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).